# Is there a way to get the session map within custom ActionMapper?

Tags: session, struts2

I'd like to get/set session parameters within a custom ActionMapper in Struts2. When I call

```
Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
```

within my custom `MyActionMapper` class, `session` is `null`.

What am I doing wrong? Do i have to configure something to actually have a session?

Thanks, Gregor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually works fine as a method within my custom `ActionMapper`:

```
private SessionMap<String, Object> getSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
    SessionMap<String, Object> session = 
        (SessionMap<String, Object>) ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

    if ( session == null ) {
        /* create a sessionMap if we don't already have one. */
        session = new SessionMap<String, Object>(request);
    }
    return session;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use `ognl #session.USER_KEY` it won't find if you use `getSession` or `setSession`.

Better take `SessionMap` from below syntax

```
SessionMap sessionmap = ActionContext.getContext().get("session") ;
```

then it will work properly.